# Unable to Invite People from Apple Developer account from any email ID

Tags: developer-tools

Trying to Invite as Admin or as Member on apple developer account not working.

Showing a alert says : The email addresses indicated above are not valid.

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same issue...

Comment: I managed to get this working by creating an App Store Connect account with that email first, which took me through the process of creating an AppleID, which then allowed me to invite that email to developer.apple. At first, it still didn't work, but after waiting about 2 min, it finally did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue. I did logout and login again and surprisingly its works for me. You can also try it , hope it will work for you too.